# Probability on a game between two teams

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> If Teams A & B are contesting in a 7-game tournament where the winner must win 4 games overall and Team A has probability $p$ of winning against Team B,
>
>  (1) What is the probability that Team A will win in $6$ matches? 
>  (2) What is the probability that Team A will win? 
>  (3) If the same teams contested in a game of $n$ matches where the winner must win $k$ matches, where $k=\displaystyle\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor+1$, what is the probability that Team A will win?

For the (1) part, for Team A to win in $6$ matches, it must have won the other $3$ and lost $2$. This can be achieved in $\displaystyle{5 \choose3}=10$ ways. And because order is irrelevant, the overall probability of the first setup should be $\displaystyle{5 \choose 3}p^3(1-p)^2$, right? And then isn't the probability of Team A winning $\displaystyle{5 \choose 3}p^4(1-p)^2$? Something seems off here, but I can't quite put my finger on it. 
For the (2) part, I shall look at the cases:

- Team A wins 4 times straight: Then the probability is $p_1$=$p^4$
- Team A loses once and wins the wins 4 times (order is irrelevant, but the loss cannot be the last match): Then the probability is $p_2=\displaystyle{4 \choose 3}p^4(1-p)=4p^4(1-p)$
- Team A loses twice and wins 4 times (again, order is irrelevant): $p_3=\displaystyle{5 \choose 3}p^4(1-p)^2=10p^4(1-p)^2$
- Team A loses thrice and wins 4 times (order is irrelevant): $p_4=\displaystyle{6 \choose 3}p^4(1-p)^3=20p^4(1-p)^3$  
  Then the overall probability is $p_f=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{4}{p_i}=p^4(1+4(1-p)+10(1-p)^2+20(1-p)^3)$

For part (3), I am not really sure what to do. I believe that I must do something with the Binomial Distribution once again, but I am at a loss. Thank you in advance for your time and effort.

Comment: Your answers to the first two questions are correct except that $p_3 = \binom{5}{3}p^4(1 - p)^2$ as you wrote above and that $p_4 = \binom{6}{3}p^4(1 - p)^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider adopting a simpler formulation by assuming that the matches are fully played out regardless of the fact that team $A$ has already won, because subsequent wins/losses can't affect the result.

Taking $p,q$ for win, loss of team A, for part two, the only point you need to remember is that team $A$ can't be allowed to lose more than $3$ matches, thus

$$P(A\; wins) \large{= \sum_{i=0}^3\binom7{i}q^ip^{7-i}}$$

Similarly, for part three, Team A can afford to lose a maximum of $\lceil{(\frac{n}{2}\rceil} -1$ matches, thus

$$P(A\;wins)=\large{ \sum_{i=0}^{\lceil{\frac {n}{2}\rceil}-1}\binom{n}{i}q^ip^{n-i}}$$

**Added note**

If playing on after team A has already won seems paradoxical, look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4219056/does-the-probability-of-team-a-winning-a-series-of-seven-games-depend-on-whether/4219083#4219083) where it has been explained in greater detail

Comment: Are you not also counting the matches that take place after the game has ended?

Comment: That is *exactly* the way for the formulation to be simplified. I am adding a link where this has been explained in greater detail.